# "LDAP bind dn value missing" error when setting up Kerberos and OpenLDAP on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: openldap, kerberos, ubuntu-22.04

I have been following [these][1] instructions for setting up Kerberos to use an existing OpenLDAP server as its backend.

I have run into a problem in the very last step. I am trying to add an existing user as a principal and I expect to see the kerberos objects added to the user's object in the LDAP database.

I can run `kinit` without issue. I authenticate and get no errors:

```
> kinit {user}/admin@{REALM}
Password for {user}/admin@{REALM}:
> echo ${?}
0
>
```

I then try to run `kadmin.local` and get the following error:

```
> kadmin.local
Authenticating as principal {user}/admin@{REALM} with password.
kadmin.local: LDAP bind dn value missing while initializing kadmin.local interface
>
```

I have gone back over all steps in the instructions and cannot see what I got wrong. Where should the `bind dn` be defined or configured?

Update:  I just found out that the `kadmind` service is not running. It fails at startup with a similar error:

```
root# systemctl status krb5-admin-server
x krb5-admin-server.service - Kerberos 5 Admin Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/krb5-admin-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/krb5-admin-server.service.d
             `-slapd-before-kdc.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-10-11 10:53:58 EDT; 18min ago
    Process: 315834 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/kadmind -nofork $DAEMON_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 315834 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 90ms

Oct 11 10:53:58 isadm-a01 systemd[1]: Started Kerberos 5 Admin Server.
Oct 11 10:53:58 isadm-a01 kadmind[315834]: kadmind: LDAP bind dn value missing while initializing, aborting
Oct 11 10:53:58 isadm-a01 kadmind[315834]: LDAP bind dn value missing while initializing, aborting
Oct 11 10:53:58 isadm-a01 systemd[1]: krb5-admin-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 11 10:53:58 isadm-a01 systemd[1]: krb5-admin-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: https://www.openldap.org/software//man.cgi?query=ldap.conf&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release  The ldap.conf configuration file is used to set system-wide defaults to be applied when running ldap clients. Users  may create an optional configuration file, ldaprc or .ldaprc, in their home directory which will be used  to  override  the  system-wide  defaults  file.  The  file  ldaprc in the current working directory is also used.

Comment: Thank you @Greg.  I confirmed that the `ldap.conf` file had the correct setting for binddn. It does. The problem persists.  Some additional info: The `systemctl status krb5-admin-server` command shows that the service failed with the same error:  `kadmind[315834]: LDAP bind dn value missing while initializing, aborting`

Comment: It turned out to be a typo in /etc/krb5.conf. I had a line for `ldap_kadmin_dn` instead of `ldap_kadmind_dn`.